# Rounding error in DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am working on a SQL query (on DB2) where we need to find difference between two decimal numbers. One of the numbers,`FEERETNUM` is already rounded to two decimal places. But the other product that I have computed, needs to be rounded.

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT ROUND (X.ANNFACTOR * X.NONINTINC,2) - X.FEERETNUM AS diff,
       X.FEERETNUM AS FEERETNUMS,
       X.NONINTINC AS NONINTINCS,
       X.I_REC_KEY AS I_REC_KEY
FROM (SELECT KPI.P_MO_ANNLZD_FACTR AS ANNFACTOR,
             KPI.A_FEE_RTRN_NUMRTR AS FEERETNUM,
             PL.A_NINT_INCM AS NONINTINC,
             KPI.I_REC_KEY AS I_REC_KEY 
      FROM DWP1.PCALC_KPI_BL_ACCT_PRD_MO_DMT AS KPI 
        INNER JOIN DWP1.PCALC_PL_BL_ACCT_PRD_MO_DMT AS PL 
          ON KPI.I_REC_KEY=PL.I_REC_KEY 
      WHERE KPI.I_PRTN='200'
      FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY) AS X
```

We are multiplying `ANNFACTOR` and `NONINTINC` and rounding it to two decimals so that we can subtract it from `FEERETNUM`. We are fetching only 100 rows so that I can run the code quickly and see results. But even with 100 rows being fetched I am getting following error message;

> Error during SQLFetch 22003(-802)[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2] SQL0802N  Arithmetic overflow or other arithmetic exception occurred.  SQLSTATE=22003

I am certain that this error is arising because of rounding function. Because when I remove rounding fn. from query, the error disappears.

Comment: any chance to post your actual data. i think there is an alienated data somewhere

Comment: "I am certain that this error is arising because of rounding function. Because when I remove rounding fn. from query, the error disappears."  ... is `ROUND` the only thing you're removing?  What about the multiplication, as well - what are the operands (and thus the results) of the multiplication?

Comment: You need to provide your table definitions, along with the previously requested sample data.

Comment: Also, have you pared down the query to make things easier to see? Why is the only table in the outer select a sub-select?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy.                                                                                    
  Here is a small data sample.  I am trying to multiply annfactor and nonintinc.                                                                                `ANNFACTOR  FEERETNUM NONINTINC I_REC_KEY`
  `1.092814371 375.65            10.34                  8922909`
  `12.16666667 139.19          10.34                   8922909`